# Can a UIView load another nib after it's initialization?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Just a question to feed my curiosity. Can a UIView after it's initialization with a nib, load another nib again?

For example, this is where I initialize my View with a certain nib:

```
private func selfInit(){
    Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed(fileName, owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(contentView)
}

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    selfInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    selfInit()
}
```

can I after the initialization of the nib with Bundle(...) I change the Nib again?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried?

Comment: Why would it not be able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Doubt that overriding the initializer to setup the initial values for setting default values for the class variables (including the UIViews) would be a good idea, but when it comes to adding a subview I would recommend to do it in the [`awakeFromNib()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib) method:

> Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an
>   Interface Builder archive, or nib file.
>
> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, **but only after all the objects in**
>   **the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives**
>   **an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and**
>   **action connections already established.**

Seems to be more appropriate method to add a subview in it; For instance, imagine that subview should has constraints with other components in the main view, you would need to guarantee that all components has been established.

Thus:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selfInit()
}
```